# Substance engine failed to load

Tags: unity-game-engine, substance

When I try to import `Substances` in `Unity`, it shows me this message in the console:

> Substance engine failed to load
>       UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
>       Substance.Game.DLLHelpers:LoadDLL(String)
>       Substance.Game.NativeFunctions:cppInitSubstance(String)
>       Substance.Game.NativeCallbacks:InitSubstance()
>       Substance.Game.SubstanceMain:Initialize()
>       Substance.Game.SubstanceMain:.cctor()
>       UnityEditor.EditorAssemblies:ProcessInitializeOnLoadAttributes()

What can I do to fix this?